# How can I validate that a user-entered password is actually the correct password for that user?

Tags: bash, shell, passwords, zsh

I have a shell script that reads a user-entered password, then later pipes that value into STDIN for a `sudo` function over ssh.

```
echo "Password for ${USER}:"
read -s password
```

and then:

```
ssh -n ${host} "echo ${password} | sudo -S <some command>"
```

However, if a user enters the wrong password, the `ssh` line fails because while the user *does* have sudo access, the password is incorrect.

#### Note: a user's (correct) password will be the same on both the host and remote machine

Does there exist a mechanism in bash to **locally** validate whether a user's password is correct?

#### Things I've tried:

- Running something like `sudo ls` and checking for a non-0 exit code (did not work)

Comment: not really clear; you cannot check locally if a remote password is good...

Comment: I think the short answer is : no. First that would be a huge breach in security, and second you're not even want to verify for a local host but for a distant one. By the way, I'm not sure it's a good idea to store the password in the script command history.

Comment: BTW, storing a password this way, and moreover echo'ing it remotly is really risk as the password will be visible in the process command on the remote

Comment: Thanks to @OznOg and Andre Gelinas for your feedback.  To clarify: I want to check whether a user's password is correct on the _local_ host - not the remote one (reason: they will be the same).  Question updated.